# Does $\operatorname{length}(M/xM) \leq \operatorname{rank}(M) \cdot \operatorname{length}(R/(x))$ hold over non-integral rings $R$?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, dimension-theory-algebra

$\DeclareMathOperator{\len}{length}
\DeclareMathOperator{\rk}{rank}$In Eisenbud's book *Commutative Algebra with a View towards Algebraic Geometry* he says:

> *The basic result of this section expresses the length of $M/aM$ for certain $R$-modules $M$ in terms of the length of $R/(a)$ and an invariant of $M$. [...] For simplicity, and because it suffices for the application, we shall assume here that $R$ is a domain.*

He then defines the rank of $M$ over $R$ as $\rk(M) = \dim_{K} K \otimes_R M$ where $K$ is the field of fractions of $R$. After that he goes on and gives the following result:

> **Lemma 11.12.**  Let $R$ be a one-dimensional Noetherian domain. If $M$ is a torsion-free $R$-module, then $$\len(M/xM) \leq \rk(M) \cdot \len(R/(x))$$ with equality if $M$ is finitely generated as an $R$-module.

Now I am wondering if there holds a similar result in the case when $R$ has zero divisors. But then, if I recall correctly, the rank is only locally well-defined.

So, can anyone give me references where this is handled in the non-integral case? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: How would you define rank locally when $R$ has zero divisors? Can you give an example?

Comment: @Youngsu I don't know. Do you know any references where something familiar to the rank is defined for modules over non-integral rings?

Comment: @Youngsu I guess I was thinking about the possibility (when I said I've heard that the rank is locally well-defined) to define the rank locally be the minimal number of generators.